# Dynamic method invocation

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods

I have two simple classes:

```
public class A
{
    public void DoSomething();
}

public class Listener
{
    public void OnDoSomethingCalled();
}
```

I want Listener.OnDoSomethingCalled() to be called automatically everytime A.DoSomething() is called. I want to do this without changing class A.  I don't want to add a delegate in A and attach Listener to that delegate. Imagine the scenario where I don't have the source code for class A.

I can't use decoration pattern here because I can't modify the code that calls A.DoSomething(). I read something about Reflection.Emit or DynamicMethod to dynamically change or define a method at runtime. Can it be applied here and how?

Comment: I'm assuming that you can not modify `A class`?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Aspect Oriented Programming with something like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp), which I believe should handle this (it rewrites the CIL).

Comment: But I have to add the attributes into the class I want to attach to. I think this is actually just a decoration pattern implementation using attributes so I don't think it's gonna work for me.

Comment: You could add something to the assembly, if you can change that, e.g. '[assembly: Trace("MyCategory", AttributeTargetTypes = "My.BusinessLayer.*")]'